# For-loop inside parallel region

Tags: c++, openmp

If there is a for-loop inside a parallel region, would for-loop be parallelized again or every thread will execute its own for-loop?

```
T sum;

#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for reduction(+: sum)
    for (;;)
    {
        T priv_var;

        sum += priv_var;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a good reason that the OpenMP `for` directive belongs to the so-called "worksharing" directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this code will cause OpenMP to parallelise the `for` loop across the threads that are spawned by the `parallel` region. However, I believe that your current `for` statement is invalid for OpenMP parallelisation. You need to explicitly provide an integer loop variable, start and end, and increment expression.

In effect, your code will then be equivalent to a single loop with `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: sum)`.

[More information on MDSN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z19s8e0)